# How do you create the first user in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running postgres in docker.

I ran `initdb` with no args as the user `postgres` but now when I run `psql` or `createuser` I get an error:

```
could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I get the same error when using the "root" user, so I don't see any way to run the sql to create the first user.

How do I create a user / role in the database when none already exist?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `initdb` command line you used. `initdb` **will** create the superuser that owns the bootstrap database.

Comment: hmm. I ran it without any arguments. I ended up recreating the docker image and now it works. Maybe I was missing a restart or something.

Comment: My postgres user may have been `ubuntu`. I saw this issue again and the correct user was in the POSTGRES_USER env var